# Why doesn't Linux Mint Boot anymore?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot

I'm still fairly new to Linux as I've only used it for a few months or so. I don't remember how recently, but fairly recently I turned on my laptop one day and Linux just decided it didn't want to boot. I have both Linux Mint 20.something and Windows 10 both installed on my laptop, so on boot I'm asked to choose between booting windows 10 or booting Linux Mint, Linux Mint is the default so It should boot automatically if I don't choose an option. So now when I either select Linux Mint or let it start automatically, all I get is some kind of error. So when Linux tries to start this is what it says.

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built in shell (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

That's all the info it gives me. is anyone able to help please?

Comment: Windows automated updates are known to assume they own the world (or at least, your entire machine). In particular, updates can enable `Fast Boot`, which caches drive information so it does not need to be reconstructed by Windows boot. But to Linux, it looks like a corrupt disk.

Answer (score 0):

Before all, first make a backup.

BE CAREFUL with the partition you choose, you can loose your data

Easy solution: Try to use a live cd with **gparted** and verify the integrity of your partition where you have installed your linux mint.

Hard solution: use the command ***fsck*** in the partition where you have installed linux mint to verify the integrity of the partition of linux mint. To check where you have installed Linux mint, you can use ***df - h*** or ***blkid***.